# Kernel Alignment and Ideal Kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

Why is $yy^T$ known as the ideal kernel? (Where $y$ is the vector of class labels and $y   \epsilon \{-1,1\}$ ) Also, what does Kernel Alignment with the ideal kernel help find?

Comment: Because such a kernel shows in black and white which examples are in same class, and which are not. In practice, if you have access to a similarity function like this, you don't need SVMs or classifiers at all :)

Comment: @xeon Can you elaborate a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Take a toy example with, say 5-dimensional vector $y$. Mark some positions as 1, some as -1. Now take the outer product $yy^T$ and see what matrix do you get. Where does 1's appear and what that means? Do you get other values than 1 and -1 in this matrix?